# Kann man „Was für ein …?“ fragen, und was bedeutet es?

Tags: meaning, phrase, question

Einmal hörte ich, in einem alten Technolied, die Konstruktion „Was für ein …?“. Seitdem verwende ich diese Konstruktion für Fragen, wie:

- „Was für ein Genus hat dieses Wort?“
- „Dein Rock ist schön. Was für ein Stoff ist das?“

Wenn ich nach die Phrase [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+f%C3%BCr+ein%22), finde ich aber wenig Fragen, nur Ausrufe wie „Was für ein Zufall!“ und „Was für ein schöner Zufall!“. Ich bin auch besorgt, dass die Phrase einen sarkastischen Beiklang hat. Zum Beispiel, ist

> „Ich studiere Halbleiterphysik.“
>   „Was für ein Fach ist das?“

als „Ha! Das ist schlecht!“ oder „Achso! Was bedeutet das?“ verstanden?

Meine Frage ist: **Was bedeutet die Frage „Was für ein …“?**

Comment: Was für ein Technolied war das denn? :-)

Comment: @Jan: Vielleicht war es Synth: [Achtung Christmas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2A3kMTZwSQ8) von "Tyskarna från Lund" (Deutschern aus Lund). Kraftwerk-Satire. (Note that it's mostly pseudo-German.)

Comment: It is correct and widely used, see here: http://www.nichtlustig.de/toondb/080115.html#restore xD

Comment: Was für ein Stoff ist das? - What kind of cloth/textile is it?

Comment: Was für eine blöde Frage ist das? :) (kleiner Spaß, meiner Meinung nach geht das i.O.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es gibt „Was für ein(e) …“ sowohl als *Teil einer Frage* als auch als *Teil eines Ausrufs*.

**Als Frage formuliert** ersetzt es im umgangssprachlichen Gebrauch oft „welche, welcher, welches“; genau genommen fragt man damit aber nach der *Natur oder Art einer Sache*.

Die Frage „Was für ein Stoff ist das?“ kann man also nach umgangssprachlicher Interpretation („Welcher Stoff ist das?“) beispielsweise mit „Wolle“ beantworten, aber korrekterweise müsste man eine Aussage über die Art oder Natur des Stoffes machen, also z. B. „ein tierischer Stoff“, „ein kratziger Stoff“ oder „ein teurer Stoff“.

**Als Ausruf gebraucht** ist es eine Verstärkung des Subjekts des Satzes, weil es in seiner Art besonders ist unter seinen Artgenossen. Beispielsweise sagt der Ausruf „Was für ein Zufall!“ etwas über die Art oder Natur des Zufalls aus, meist dass er größer ist als andere Zufälle, die man zuvor erlebt hat.

Oft wird aber umgangssprachlich damit auch nur gesagt, dass es sich überhaupt um einen Zufall handelt, ohne größeren Wert auf eine Beschreibung seiner Natur zu legen. Vergleichbar im Englischen: “What a coincidence!”

„Was für ein“ kann man auch gut für **sarkastische Aussagen** einsetzen, indem man es in einer rhetorischen Frage verwendet. *Bei der Bestimmung, ob die Frage rhetorisch gemeint ist, kommt es stark auf die Betonung an.* – „Was ist das denn für ein Fach?“ wäre dann die implizite Aussage, dass dieses Fach ein besonderes (z. B. ein besonders nutzloses) unter allen Fächern ist.

*Edit:* Zwischen Ausruf und Frage gibt es einen Fall-Unterschied, der sich in der Beugung von „ein“ widerspiegelt: „Was für ein Zufall!“ nutzt den Nominativ, aber „Was für einen Zufall meinst Du?“ nutzt den Akkusativ. Das macht sich allerdings nur bei männlichen Wörtern bemerkbar, denn beim weiblichen und sächlichen Wortgeschlecht sind die unbestimmten Artikel (eine, ein) in beiden Fällen gleich.

Comment: @Jan: Man könnte im letzten Absatz ergänzen, dass die Betonung dann auf _das_ liegen würde.

Comment: @Hendrik: oder auf "Fach". Manche würden vielleicht sogar das "was" etwas anders betonen... Daher lieber nicht :-)

Comment: @Jan: OK. Gerade in diesem Beispielsatz finde ich die Betonung auf _Fach_ merkwürdig, aber Du hast recht, dass die Betonung im Prinzip auch dort liegen kann.

Comment: `daß er größer ist als andere Zufälle` - Da Zufälle von besonders kleiner Wahrscheinlichkeit sind, erscheint mir 'großer Zufall' unpassend, um zu unterstreichen, wie unwahrscheinlich oder selten er ist - aber das nur am Rande. ;)

Comment: @user - Der Ausdruck `grosser Zufall` wird schon dazu verwendet, die Unwahrscheinlichkeit von Etwas zu unterstreichen.

Comment: 'Schon' im Sinne von 'wirklich'? Ich finde es schon unpassend; dennoch. Beim Roulette trifft man einen 4er-Block mit p=4/37, die richtige Zahl dagegen mit p=1/37. Die richtige Zahl trifft man also mit kleinerer Wahrscheinlichkeit. Es ist noch unwahrscheinlicher, sie zu treffen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Phrase "Was für ein" wird je nach Genus des nachfolgenden Substantivs gebeugt.

Maskulin - "der Stoff" - Was für ein Stoff ist das?

Feminin - "die Suppe" - Was für eine Suppe ist das?

Neutrum - "das Buch" - Was für ein Buch ist das?

Allerdings kann "Was für ein..." auch als Ausdruck des Entrüstens gebraucht werden.

> Du sammelst Bierdeckel? Was für ein Hobby ist das denn?

oder

> Du sammelst Bierdeckel? Was ist das denn für ein Hobby?