# Stammt "was für" aus dem Hochdeutschen?

Tags: phrase, etymology

> Was für (Welche) Filme magst du?

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuer_welch) sagt nur:

> Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter
>   was für [ein] (welch [zur Angabe der Art oder Qualität]: was für
>   ein Kleid möchten Sie kaufen?; aus was für Gründen auch immer; was hat
>   das Ganze für einen Sinn?; was für eine Tat!)

Irgendwie hört es sich bei genauem Hinhören wie eine künstliche (falsche?) grammatikalische Konstruktion an. Wo kommt diese Konstruktion ursprünglich her?

Comment: Verwandte Frage: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/kann-man-was-fur-ein-fragen-und-was-bedeutet-es

Comment: @close-voter: ich denke, diese Frage hier ist kein exaktes Duplikat der von mir verlinkten Frage. Sie geht in eine andere Richtung: bei der verlinkten Frage geht es darum, wie "was für" verwendet wird und was es bedeutet. *Hier* geht es meiner Meinung nach eher um den grammatischen Hintergrund - welche Grammatik-Regel läßt "was für" zu?

Comment: M.E. bringt es bei feststehenden Ausdrücken oder Redewendungen nicht viel, nach grammatischen Regeln zu fragen. Auf „was für“ sind natürlich bestimmte [grammatische Regeln anwendbar](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-was_fuer.html), aber es ist ja gerade typisch für Wendungen, das sie als feststehend akzeptiert sind. Deswegen ist auch die Frage „hochdeutsch“ oder „nicht hochdeutsch“ nicht sonderlich sinnvoll - die einfache Antwortet lautet schlicht „ja“. Wenn das nicht gemeint ist, sollte m.E. der Titel angepasst werden.

Comment: Ich habe eine Seite gefunden, die meint, dass [es Österreichisch ist](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-11385-at-was+f%C3%BCr+eine+,+-r+,+-s.html). Irgendwie, habe ich meine Zweifel...

Comment: @tohu ich hab den Titel mal umformuliert um den etymologischen Charakter der Frage klarer zu machen, den Upvotes nach war die Frage aber den meisten eindeutig genug. Redewendungen müssen per se ja nicht ungrammatikalisch sein. Die Frage ist wohl eher wie sich trotz Grammatik solch eine ungelenke Redewendung hat bilden können. Mir fällt jetzt auch spontan keine ähnliche Konstruktion ein in einer Redewendung oder sonst. Hochdeutsch. Mir fiel das nur beim eigenen Lesen von "was für" in der Südtirol Frage auf.

Comment: Was für eine Frage, was für ein Deutsch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein paar Zitate, die darauf hindeuten mögen, daß es sich um eine wohletablierte hochdeutsche Wendung handelt:

> Was für ein Gegengewicht doch die Elenden dem Gefühl der verdienten Schande anhängen mögen? ([Kant: Briefwechsel, Brief 802, Von Iohann Ernst Lüdeke, 6. März 1798](http://korpora.org/kant/briefe/802.html))
>
> Was ist sie für ein Element; was für ein Umgestalter; was für ein Ansturm in der Luft ihrer Zeit ([Rainer Maria Rilke, Briefe I, Letter to Clara Rilke, September 4, 1908, 247](http://books.google.com/books?id=J2RtYOtRGzEC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=rilke%20%22was%20f%C3%BCr%22&source=bl&ots=9RijXek8mi&sig=KgjwRktdjjvuLqQkOP0PDxzOK3Q&hl=en&ei=YpPGTu-aE_L74QTcj_xU&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=rilke%20%22was%20f%C3%BCr%22&f=false))
>
> Du lieber Gott, was für ein armes gutes Tier der Mensch ist! ([Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, Tagebuch der italienischen Reise, 30.9.1786](http://www.goethe-zitate.com/sprueche-zitate-goethe/auf-der-italienreise-ueber-mensch-und-tier/))
>
> Das Schwert zeigt deutlich an, was für Kinder es unter sich hat, nämlich nichts als verdammte Schurken [...]. ([Martin Luther: Ob Kriegsleute in seligem Stande sein können, 1526](http://www.projektwerkstatt.de/religion/luther/luther_zitate.html))
>
> Gott straft selbst, aber heimlich, entweder durch Armut, eine böse Frau, durch ungehorsame Kinder und auf viele andere Weise. Was für eine Strafe wünscht du also? ([Die Werke Martin Luthers in neuer Auswahl für die Gegenwart. Herausgegeben von Kurt Aland. Band 9: Tischreden. Dritte, völlig neu bearbeitete Auflage, Stuttgart 1960; Reclam-Ausgabe, Ditzingen 1987, S. 655](http://www.theologe.de/theologe3.htm))

Answer (score 3):

Ich behaupte, daß "was für" hochdeutsch ist (um die ursprüngliche Frage zu beantworten).

Ich stütze mich (indirekt) auf den Duden. Dort steht beim [Pronomen "was"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/was_Fragewort_welches) unter "Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter":

> was ein … (umgangssprachlich; was für ein …, welch ein …: du weißt doch selbst, was ein Aufwand das ist; was 'n fieser Kerl!; was 'n Glück!)

"was ein" wird als umgangssprachlich deklariert. Danach folgt dudentypisch eine Aufzählung der hochsprachlichen Alternativen, angeführt durch "was für ein", gefolgt von "welch ein".

Da "was für ein" hier als eine hochsprachliche Alternative gelistet ist, gehe ich einfach davon aus, daß es auch hochdeutsch ist. (Jedenfalls habe ich es bis jetzt noch nicht erlebt, daß eine weitere umgansprachliche Alternative in der Erklärung folgt, ohne als solche explizit gekennzeichnet zu sein.)